# Зачем нужно опережающее объявление?

Tags: c++

Есть два класса - MdiChild и MainWindow. В заголовке MainWindow приведено объявление:

```
class MdiChild;
```

А вот в самом `mainwindow.cpp` подключен `mdichild.h`. С какой целью так делается? Можно ведь подключить `mdichild.h` в `mainwindow.h`? Или нет?

P.S. Название вопроса написал по-дурацки. Ломал голову. Исправьте если кто придумает нормально.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

То, что Вы привели - это распростанненный хак. Для того, что бы иметь указатель или ссылку на класс, компилятору не нужно знать реальный размер класса. А не подключают заголовок по одной простой причине - ускорить компиляцию. Компилятор не будет разбирать большие заголовки и как следствие, компиляция может ускорится очень сильно.
Так к примеру, рекомендуют делать в Google.
В некоторых случаях даже создают отдельно компактные h файлы для включения. Более того, в стандартной библиотеке есть даже файл заголовка `iosfwd` - он нужен тогда, когда нужно использовать классы с iostream, но только указателиссылки (например, в заголовочном файле объявляется перегруженный оператор <<)

Comment: Вот оно как. Я точно когда-то слышал про оптимизацию таким образом. Но не про ту оптимизацию думал. Естественно это должно ускорить оптимизацию! Спасибо. Интересно)

Comment: Ох, я так делал, но не знал. как всё работает. Теперь всё понятно, спасибо :)

Answer (score 3):

Это называется предварительное объявление класса, для того чтобы этот класс можно было использовать до его определения.

Comment: А какое преимущество это даст по сравнению с подключением заголовка?

Comment: Дело в том, что эти классы могут иметь взаимную зависимость (они оба используют друг друга) и тогда подключить файл с объвлением класса невозможно, приходиться использовать предварительное объявление.