# Qt. Как обратится к объекту класса-родителя из объекта класса потомка?

Tags: qt, наследование

Суть вопроса такова:

Существует родительский класс `MainWindow`, наследованный от `QMainWindow`. Данный класс является основным окном приложения и в его заголовке описаны все дочерние виджеты, использующийся в программе, такие как чат, таблицы и пр.

Каждый дочерний класс должен иметь доступ к некоторым функциям родителя, при чём не просто функций из области видимости, а к публичным полям. Лично мне это необходимо, что бы каждый из виджетов мог вызвать другой виджет, ведь указатели на все виджеты содержит родительский класc.

Да, в Qt есть возможность передавать адрес родителя потомку, однако передаваемый адрес будет преобразован к `QObject` или к `QWidget`. Но такой вариант не подходит, поскольку мне нужно обратится по указателю именно к `MainWindow`.

> Почему бы тебе просто не привести указатель к MainWindow?

Потому что конструкция `MainWindow *mainwindow = ((MainWindow*)parentWidget())` меняет тип указателя `mainwindow` на `QWidget`.

> Почему ты используешь такой примитивный способ приведения?

Я использовал все, найденные способы и результат был тем же, либо возвращался `0`.

Ещё не маловажный аспект:

Что бы в конструкторе класса потомка объявить параметр для указателя на родительский класс `MainWindow`, необходимо прописать в хедере потомка.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
```

Но и в хедере родителя, имеется инклуд на потомка, например

```
#include "chat.h"
```

Возникает рекурсия, которая убирается средствами  предпроцессорных команд `#ifdef` и.т.д.

Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование перекрестного include не самый хороший вариант. Если требуется обратная связь от потомка к родителю, я бы объявил у потомков набор сигналов, на действие в дочернем виджете испускал бы соответствующий сигнал, а у основного окна присоединил бы сигналы к нужным слотам. Это отменит необходимость включать заголовочный файл родителя в файле потомка и уберет необходимость в приведении типа.

Answer (score 1):

> передаваемый адрес будет преобразован к QObject или к QWidget

Адрес не будет преобразован никак, т.к. это, в любом случае, просто числовое значение =) А чтобы как-то трактовать ту область памяти, на которую он указывает, и существует такое понятие, как *тип указателя*.

> Потому что конструкция MainWindow *mainwindow =
>   ((MainWindow*)parentWidget()) меняет тип указателя mainwindow на
>   QWidget.

Это должно работать как и ожидается, проверяйте еще раз. А еще лучше - использовать `qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parentWidget())`.

Проблему с хедерами нужно решать с помощью [forward declaration](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41844/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), если кроме адреса ничего знать о типе не нужно.

Comment: Forward declaration не поможет, надо дергать методы родителя из потомка

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Дергать их обязательно в хэдере?) В файле реализации можно инклудить что угодно и как угодно, никакой рекурсии не будет. Нужно стараться выносить реализацию методов из хэдера.

Comment: Есть вариант включить хедер родителя в cpp потомка, а в хэлере потомка форвард-декларировать класс, только щас сообразил, что именно вы предлагаете :) Но все равно, если требуются такие извращения, значит налицо проблема проектирования и надо менять саму систему взаимодействия

Comment: Как бы вы спроектировали подобную систему?

Comment: @Prost971 Вы же в Qt, используйте сигнально-слотовую связь! Биндингом сигналов/слотов между дочертиними виджетами может заниматься родитель. Это поможет сохранить модульность, при которой потомки не будут знать друг о друге слишком много. Если связь более тесная (много различных вызовов и сложная логика взаимодействия), стоит подумать о менеджере между потомками, к которому они подключались бы. Конечно, все зависит от задачи.

Comment: Если даже исключить QT. Имея множество классов и один главный,как их связать с доступом друг к другу?

Comment: @Prost971 Какого рода доступ? Приведите аналогию, как они взаимодействуют?

Скажем, если это логика сильно связанных виджетов, которые отображают свой определенный кусок состояния, то есть смысл вообще вынести ее в некоторую общую модель, а виджеты "отупить" до чтения данных из модели по событию "что-тоПоменялось".

Если это полностью независимые блоки, которые пинают друг друга, которые при этом не должны точно знать об остальных, то это либо передача указателя каждого каждому, либо посредник, который управляет передачей.

Comment: @Prost971 
Скажем, если это бильярд, то между "глупыми" шарами (которые лишь хранят данные о своем местоположении и векторе движения) нужен посредник - бильярдный стол (который хранит список шаров и отвечает за соударение).
Но если у нас телефонная станция, то посредник тупо биндит связи (сигналы/слоты), а абоненты уже сами передают информацию и реагируют на нее.

Comment: Ну, по сути, у меня виджеты не сильно связаны, но, скажем, к чату должен быть доступ у всех, к базам данных, только у соответствующих форм...

Comment: Так то, родитель у меня и является их местом хранения указателей. Проблема лишь в типизированности языка.

Comment: @Prost971 У языка-то проблем с типизацией нет) Заведите общего родителя для своих виджетов (с операциями доступа к чату) и кастуйте к нему всех подряд.

Comment: И вот на этом моменте возник мой основной вопрос о связи потомков с родителем.  Но я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Лучший вариант наверное все-таки сигналы в потомках, как описано ниже.
Самый простой явным приведение, это должно работать.
Или сделать синглтон:
В `MainWindow.h` пишешь

```
public:
static MainWindow* instance();
private:
static MainWindow* mInst;

MainWindow.cpp

MainWindow* MainWindow::mInst=NULL;
MainWindow* MainWindow:: instance()
{
if (mInst==NULL)
  mInst = new MainWindow();
return mInst;
}
```

В дочерних классах вызываешь

```
MainWindow::instance()->нужнаяФункция
```